# cannot set Broadcast Receiver For Internet Connectivity as follow is my code

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have done with this method class in util package, but issue is how to call this method for checking the internet connectivity, please help.
As My code is working well with no error

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "NetworkChangeReceiver";
private boolean isConnected = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
    isNetworkAvailable(context);
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    if (!isConnected) {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet availablle via Broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        isConnected = true;
                        // do your processing here ---
                        // if you need to post any data to the server or get
                        // status
                        // update from the server
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet NOT availablle via Broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    isConnected = false;
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using broadcast receiver, your app will be automatically notified when
>   there is a change in network connection.

```
   boolean isConnected = NetworkChangeReceiver.isNetworkAvailable(YourACTIVITY.this);
   System.out.println("STATUS"+isConnected );
```

Comment: i'm getting error at .isNetworkAvailable asking to make it static or create a new method

Comment: @SandeepManmode Same work https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/